# Magento 2.2.3- ACL Permissions not Working for Customer module

Tags: magento2, acl

I have created a user and provide a new created  role customer which have access to customer module only . When we logged in with that particular user , we are able to see the customer list but when click on edit customer 
it gives This page isn’t working, currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
[image]

Comment: have you given permissions in your controller?

Comment: This is default magento customer module, you can check the same in your existing application.

Comment: After creating role and user, have you run command like caching, indexing?

Comment: yes I have run caching but not indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above posted question is bug reproduced in  Magento 2.2.x 
and it is **throwing invalid parameter configuration provided for argument**.
The solution for the above issue is to add the code in file 
endor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php after line 149.

```
if (isset($componentArguments['block']) && !$componentArguments['block']) {
            return null;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: But Here a new challenge that how to override the above file.

Comment: Can you please update your question instead of answering?

Comment: @sv3n Question is as it is what I was facing the problem. On searching I have found a temporary solution to edit core file and this will also  fix in magento new release. But right now instead of editing core file I am trying to find some way to override the file.