# Magento 2.2.2- ACL Permissions not Working for Customer module

Tags: customer, backend, magento2.2.2

I have created a new admin user and set a new user role which have access to  only customer section.
When we logged in with that particular user , we are able to see the customer list but when clicked on edit customer it gives below error

> This page isn’t working, currently unable to handle this request. HTTP
>   ERROR 500

I referred [Magento 2.2.3- ACL Permissions not Working for Customer module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248585/magento-2-2-3-acl-permissions-not-working-for-customer-module)  and tried adding the fix in UiComponentFactory.php but it doesnt work and there is no error log or system log. Any solution?

Edit: On adding logger i am getting the following error:

```
[2019-04-08 16:21:43] main.INFO: Invalid block type: Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View [] []

[2019-04-08 16:21:52] main.CRITICAL: Class XXXX\YYYY\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab\View does not exist [] []
```

Comment: app/bootstrap.php uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: app/bootstrap.php? can you please specify the full path? and what is the need to uncomment that line?

Comment: /var/www/html/project_name/app/bootstrap.php  line no 12 to dispaly error

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Let me try it.

Comment: Class XXXX\YYYY\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab\View  class is define but not exit in your code

Comment: Hi, I got it fixed using the fix given in the link i mentioned in my question.. Thank you...

Comment: most welcome...